# Adding text to table messes up alignment HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sort of date/time selection for my website.

css:

```
.top {
    background-color: #82ceff !important;
}

.time-table-block{
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    margin-top : -4px;
    margin-bottom : -4px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-table;
    text-align: center;
    border:  1px #666666 solid;
}

.time-table-block:hover{
    background-color:  #b9b7b7;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="time-table" >

     <div class="time-table-block white-text top">Dagen</div>
     <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>ma</b></div>
     <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>di</b></div>
     <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>wo</b></div>
     <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>do</b></div>
     <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>vr</b></div>
     <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>za</b></div>
     <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>zo</b></div>

     <div class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="ma-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="di-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="wo-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="do-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="vr-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="za-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="zo-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>

     <div class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="ma-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="di-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="wo-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="do-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="vr-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="za-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="zo-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>     

     <div class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="ma-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="di-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="wo-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="do-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="vr-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="za-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
     <div id="zo-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>

</div>
```

so far everything looks fine. I can add text to the top cells without any problem and there are no alignment problems.

Now for the issue:
I am also trying to add text to the most left columns (see jsfiddle to see it more clearly) but this causes the alignment to go all over the place.
I have tried to remove all the margins i could find. i have also experimented using padding etc but i just cannot seem to fix the issue. Any help would be much appreciated

```css
.top{
    background-color: #82ceff !important;
}

.time-table-block{
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    margin-top : -4px;
    margin-bottom : -4px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-table;
    text-align: center;
    border:  1px #666666 solid;
}

.time-table-block:hover{
    background-color:  #b9b7b7;
}
```

```html
<div id="time-table" >
    
    <p>Good</p>
    
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top">Dagen</div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>ma</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>di</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>wo</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>do</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>vr</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>za</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>zo</b></div>
                     
    <div class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="ma-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="di-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="wo-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="do-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="vr-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="za-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="zo-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
                        
    <div class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="ma-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="di-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="wo-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="do-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="vr-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="za-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="zo-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
                       
                        
    <div class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="ma-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="di-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="wo-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="do-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="vr-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="za-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="zo-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
                        
</div>
                    
                    
                    
<div id="time-table" >
    <p>Bad</p>      
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top">Dagen</div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>ma</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>di</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>wo</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>do</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>vr</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>za</b></div>
    <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>zo</b></div>
                     
    <div class="time-table-block">i want</div>
    <div id="ma-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="di-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="wo-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="do-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="vr-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="za-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="zo-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    
    <div class="time-table-block">to add</div>
    <div id="ma-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="di-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="wo-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="do-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="vr-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="za-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="zo-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    
                        
    <div class="time-table-block">text here</div>
    <div id="ma-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="di-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="wo-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="do-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="vr-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="za-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    <div id="zo-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
                        
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: 
https://jsfiddle.net/a4ebbmzf/13/

Comment: Why don't you use an actual tr td table?

Comment: I also don't understand the use of negative margins. Like @FaustoNA said, why not use actual `tables` instead of mimicking them? Au contrary to what you might have heard, `tables` are fine. For tabular data.

Comment: Ok i always thought that tables we're old and not used anymore. Also the negative margins are there so that the inline-table setting does not put spacing in between the cells.

Comment: No offense, but all those divs are unhealthy for the eyes, try a good ole tr td and it'll work better and with less code.

Comment: @Vudew they are 'old' (and a big no-no) if you are talking about using them for _layouts_, but for _tabular data_ they are simply perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using `table` for this. But if you really want to do it with `div`...

You need to define it as one table in the css, rather than a load of individual ones. Set the outer div to `display:table`, wrap your rows in a div with `display:table-cell`, and set the individual cells to `display:table-cell`.

```css
.top {
  background-color: #82ceff !important;
}

.time-table {
  display: table;
}

.time-table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.time-table-block {
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px #666666 solid;
  display: table-cell;
}

.time-table-block:hover {
  background-color: #b9b7b7;
}
```

```html
<div id="time-table">

    <p>Good</p>
    <div class="time-table-row">
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top">Dagen</div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>ma</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>di</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>wo</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>do</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>vr</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>za</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>zo</b></div>
    </div>

    <div class="time-table-row">
        <div class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="ma-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="di-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="wo-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="do-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="vr-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="za-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="zo-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="time-table-row">
        <div class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="ma-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="di-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="wo-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="do-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="vr-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="za-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="zo-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="time-table-row">
        <div class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="ma-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="di-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="wo-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="do-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="vr-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="za-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="zo-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="time-table">
    <p>Bad</p>
    <div class="time-table-row">
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top">Dagen</div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>ma</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>di</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>wo</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>do</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>vr</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>za</b></div>
        <div class="time-table-block white-text top"><b>zo</b></div>
    </div>

    <div class="time-table-row">
        <div class="time-table-block">i want</div>
        <div id="ma-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="di-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="wo-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="do-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="vr-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="za-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="zo-morning" class="time-table-block"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="time-table-row">
        <div class="time-table-block">to add</div>
        <div id="ma-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="di-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="wo-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="do-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="vr-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="za-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="zo-noon" class="time-table-block"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="time-table-row">
        <div class="time-table-block">text here</div>
        <div id="ma-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="di-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="wo-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="do-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="vr-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="za-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
        <div id="zo-evening" class="time-table-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```